# How to make asynchronous function work like a regular one?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, synchronous

I have a code that XMLHttpRequest. It's a object to send request to server and it's asynchronous so when I want to receive the response I need to provide the callback function to `onreadystatechange` property of this object. And this function is called after response being received:

```
function send()
{
   XMLHttpRequest req = new...
   req.onreadystatechange = answer;
}

function answer()
{
   //handling the answer...
}
```

So it's great but I don't want to use new function to handle answer so I do it anonymous:

```
function send()
{
   XMLHttpRequest req = new...
   req.onreadystatechange = function ()
   {
         //handling the answer...
   };
}
```

But now  i want to use the result of send function in another function for example to display result:

```
display(send())
```

So how to make this work? Something like:

```
function send()
{
   XMLHttpRequest req = new...
   req.onreadystatechange = function ()
   {
         //handling the answer...
         return result; //where result is returned by send function
   };
}
```

Is there any way to do this so that other JS code will still work while this code will handle the response?

Comment: possible duplicate of [simulating a synchronous XmlHttpRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809931/simulating-a-synchronous-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: +Andrew Marshall Not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With asynchronous functions you need to do it the opposite way.  Instead of saying `display(send())` you need to sue `send(display)`

```
function send(callback)
{
   XMLHttpRequest req = new...
   req.onreadystatechange = function ()
   {
         //handling the answer...
         callback(result);
   };
}
```

Trying to write `display(send())` won't work.  The `send()` function produces a value asynchronously but returns promptly.  It can't return the result of the async operation.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `readystatechange` handler, the response is available on `req.responseText`. You should put your call to `display()` inside that event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use synchronous AJAX call:

```
XMLHttpRequest req = new...
var result = null;
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (req.readyState == 4) {
    if (req.status == 200) {
       result = req.responseText;
    }
  }
};
req.open('GET', url, false);  //async = false
return result;
```

But this is a poor practice and not an idiomatic way of working with JavaScript. Quoting [Synchronous and asynchronous requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest):

> **Note:** You shouldn't use synchronous `XMLHttpRequests` because, due to the inherently asynchronous nature of networking, there are various ways memory and events can leak when using synchronous requests.

You know how to use callbacks, why not simply:

```
send(display)
```

Comment: I wouldn't even suggest using synchronous XHR -- [it's a worse than poor practice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7337091/201952).